# I want to list all the files in a directory

Tags: file, shell

My code does not work. In the `if`-statement it says "too many arguments". I know there are alternative ways to do this but I want to find out what is wrong with my code.

```
for fname in "*"
do
  h=$fname
  if [ -f $h ]
  then
    echo $fname
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the double quotes around `*` see:

```
for fname in *
do
  h=$fname
  if [ -f $h ]
  then
    echo $fname
  fi
done
```

hope this will work.

> Double quotes: Variables are expanded when enclosed in double quotes.

That's why your code is throwing the error: "too many arguments".

Answer (score 0):

```
read LOCATION
for filename in $LOCATION
do
    if [[ -d $filename ]]; then
        echo "$filename /"
    elif [[ -f $PASSED ]]; then
        echo "$filename *"
    else
        echo "$filename is not valid"
    exit 1
    fi
done
```